# SOAP error log, what's the issue?

Tags: php, soap

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.21
Content-type: text/html

**Fatal error**: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://fakeurl.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl' : Extra content at the end of the document
in /home/alvinn/public_html/fakeurl.com/api_details/price_update_cron_job/126_last_price_update.php:7
Stack trace:
 #0 /home/alvinn/public_html/fakeurl.com/api_details/price_update_cron_job/126_last_price_update.php(7): SoapClient->SoapClient('http:/ /fakeur...')
 #1 {main}
thrown in **/home/alvinn/public_html/fakeurl.com/api_details/price_update_cron_job/126_last_price_update.php** on line **7**

This is what is on line 6:
$host       = "fakeurl.com/index.php";

This is what is on line 7:
$proxy      = new SoapClient("http://".$host."/api/v2_soap/?wsdl"); //soap handle

Anyone knows the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess that `$host` should be a host and set as follows

```
$host = "fakeurl.com";
```

But apart from that why not download "http://".$host."/api/v2_soap/?wsdl" to your browser and post the output from *view page source*.

Comment: Gave that a try, ended up with line 11 problem <br/> $sessionId  = $proxy->login((object)array('username' => 'name', 'apiKey' => 'pw1234'));

Comment: At least the error is not on line 7 - You need to learn on how to debug as we could be here a long time. A good technique is to comment out code from line 12 onwards. Then work out what is wrong in line 11. Add a few more lines. Repeat.

Comment: BTW need to differentiate between PHP code and HTML tags. `<br/` is a HTML tag